# Not Acceptable?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-security

My site is running but I could not log in to admin dashboard, got this error

```
Not Acceptable!
An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.
```

After googling I found out it has to do with mod_security. I tried every approach to fix it: changed my plugin folder name, tried disabling mod_security with .htaccess but the error remains the same.

Are there other alternatives that I could take?

Comment: Is this self hosted? If not contact your provider who can help disable the appropriate ModSecurity rule to allow this to work.

Comment: Thank you BazzaDP, yes indeed it was nothing wrong with the wordpress or the code. It was blocked for security as of brute force login attempt. So, I did contact with my hosting provider and the problem was solved less than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult question! To be honest, I wouldn't try to fix it. I would suggest copying files and database to a local WordPress. If everything is running on you local machine, I would delete the WordPress server version and install a new WordPress and copy the database and all the files.

If you think of the hours, you try to fix it instead of copy the whole WordPress and install a new one.

Answer (score 0):

please delete you .htaccess file from the root directory and try to login into wp-admin. Once login gets successfully then regenerate the .htaccess file.

For regenerate the .htaccess file you need to follow the below steps:

`Go to setting -> permalink -> change permalink into default`.

And save the setting.

After save setting then change permalink into the post.

Now you can see that the .htaccess file gets generated successfully.